# What's the relationship between the riemannian metric and Jacobi field?

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, curvature

I encounter to the question in reading the following Excise:

> Let  $(M,g)$ be a $m$-dimensional Riemannian manifold, and $(r,\theta^1,\theta^2,\ldots,\theta^{m-1})$ be the (geodesic) polar coordinate. Prove that, if $M$ is a space form, i.e., with the constant (sectional) curvature $K$, then $g$ has the following expression (by Gauss's Lemma):
>   $$
> \newcommand{\rd}{\mathrm d}
> \rd s^2=(\rd r)^2+(f(r))^2h_{ij}(\theta)\rd\theta^i\rd\theta^j,
> $$
>   where the $m-1$-dimensional metric $(\rd\sigma)^2=h_{ij}(\theta)\rd\theta^i\rd\theta^j$ has  constant sectional curvature $1$, and 
>   $$
> f(r)=\begin{cases}
> \sin(\sqrt{Kr^2})/\sqrt{K},&K>0\\
> r,&K=0\\
> \sinh(\sqrt{-Kr^2})/\sqrt{-K},&K<0.
> \end{cases}
> $$

I already know that the Jacobo-field $J$ ($J(0)=0$, $|\dot J(0)|=1$ and $J$ is perpendicular to the base geodesic curve $\gamma(t)$) for manifold with constant sectional curvature $K$ is
$$
J(t)=f(t)W(t),
$$
where $f(t)$ is defined as above and $W(t)$ is a unit parallel vector filed along $\gamma$ with $W(t)\bot\dot\gamma(t)=T(t)$.

So my question is that: can we give a proof that based on the Jacobi-field? If not, what's the relation between the two problem?

In fact, I don't know how the solve the first problem, and try to use Jacobi-field to give a proof without no results.

Comment: After I read the site meta, I think my question will be more prefer post on MO [the link](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/89061/whats-the-relationship-between-the-riemannian-metric-and-jacobi-field).